cannot view exported UV maps in gltf
I need to access multiple UVs of a mesh I export in blender. however I cannot see the exported UV maps of my mesh in my browser console. UVs - (123,lefty,righty)
enter image description here
now when i access the UVs of that mesh in browser i dont see them
not able to view it in my browser console
